# Error:'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to encode a model that uses a squeeze-exctitation block.

I'm cluless about the error. Please suggest alternatives.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential,Model
from keras.layers import,Input,Dense,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,GlobalAveragePooling2D,BatchNormalization,Lambda,Conv2DTranspose,Reshape,Add,Multiply
import numpy as np
import io



x_inp=Input(shape=(6,8,128))
print(np.shape(x_inp))

def SEblock(x,cn):
   sh_x=x
   x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
   x=Dense(cn//16,activation='relu')(x)
   x=Dense(cn,activation='sigmoid')(x)
   x=Reshape((1,1,cn))(x)
   x=sh_x*x
   y=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
   return y
y=SEblock(x_inp,128)

model=Model(inputs=x_inp,outputs=y)
```

Error message when the above code was run:
node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes' in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992434/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-inbound-nodes-in-keras).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
x=sh_x*x
```

with

```
x = Multiply()([sh_x, x])
```